# How to store strings in an array in solidity?

Tags: solidity, string

I am trying to build a simple application on ethereum where strings can be added/deleted from an array and the contents of this array can be shown in a frontend UI.

The basic structure of the smart contract is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract ExampleApp {
  <string array over here>

  function add(string x) public {

  }

  function delete(string x) public{

  }
}
```

I have 2 questions: How can I initialise a string array and secondly how to delete a specific item from the string array? Do I have to iterate through the array to find the string or is there some simpler way?

Comment: This is such a common struggle, I wrote a cheat sheet about it over here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity

Answer (score 1):

Initializing a dynamic length string array is done just like any other type:

```
string[] someStrings;
```

Deleting a specific item from an array of any type by the value itself is not possible without looping thru all elements until you find the target element. You could use [something like a `Set`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#using-for) instead, though that's not a native type in Solidity.